# Guyana visa query

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, guyana

I am an Indian passport holder and I have a valid USA B1/B2 visa.
If I want to enter Guyana, do I require a Guyana visa? Is there a visa on arrival or do I get visa-free entry with my US visa?

Answer (score 2):

Having a quick look at the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.minfor.gov.gy/visa-entry-requirements-countries/) website, Indian citizens do need a visa irrespective of any US visa/status.

> COUNTRIES WHOSE NATIONALS DO NOT REQUIRE VISAS TO ENTER GUYANA
>
> 38. India for holders of Diplomatic/Service Passports

If you have a diplomatic passport then no visa is needed.

Comment: answered just before me! only difference is i've added they'll have a better chance of getting a visa as they've been vetted by a strict country already.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a Diplomatic/Service Passport, Indian citizens require a visa, they do not take into account visas for other countries, but having got a visa for a strict country like The USA, you'll have a better chance of being granted a visa.

[link to visa free countries](http://www.minfor.gov.gy/visa-entry-requirements-countries/)

India is only on there is you have a Diplomatic/Service Passport.